# Html Agillity Pack - Remove duplicate br tags while ignoring whitespace

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am try to remove duplicate `br` tags which I can do using the following code:

```
if (doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//br") != null)
{
    var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//br").ToArray();
    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
        if (node.PreviousSibling != null && node.PreviousSibling.Name == "br")
        {
            node.Remove();        
        }
    }
}
```

With the above code i can remove as an example:

```
this is an example <br><br><br><br> more text for example
```

Which will output:

```
this is an example <br><br> more text for example
```

But if the `br` tags have a whitespace i.e. like the below:

```
this is an example <br><br> <br><br> more text for example
```

Then it does not ignore the whitespace. I would like to be able to remove duplicate `br` tags while ignoring whitespaces.

Hopefully I have been as clear as possible if you require further information please let me know and I will amend my question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use XPath

```
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//br[following-sibling::br]").ToList();
foreach(var node in nodes)
{
    node.Remove();
}
```

This will replace all successive `br`'s with a single `br`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this how can i keep two `br` tags.

Comment: @Mannie remove half of the `nodes` :)

Comment: removing half won't work as if there are more `br` tags in parts of the document and less i.e. 2 in another it would remove on a first match.. Ideally i need to have two `br` tags left instead of one

Comment: @Mannie you can try `//br[following-sibling::br[2]]`

Comment: @har07 yes tried that already but didn't work. Still the same output.

Comment: @Mannie I meant `for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Count; i += 2) nodes[i].Remove();`

Comment: @Eser yes thats what i tried but if there is only two `br` tags it then removes one. Ideally should only be removing above two tags only..